# Use iOS 16 wallpaper in iOS 17

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone just updated itself, and its wallpaper. How do I keep my old wallpaper?

It was using the default wallpaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The good thing is that you were using the default wallpaper, you could just find it with a quick search online.

Comment: That's what I've done. The only difference is it doesn't partially overlap the clock like this

Comment: @theonlygusti Do you have "Depth Effect" enabled? You can enable It when editing your Lock Screen.